# Why this command not found when i'm comparing strings in an array?

Tags: string, bash, compare

My sample code is here

```
#!/bin/bash
file="output2.txt"
numbers="$(cut -d',' -f2 output2.txt)"
lines="$(cut -f2 output2.txt)"
hours="$(cut -d',' -f1 output2.txt)"
array_numbers=( $numbers )
lines_array=( $lines )
hours_array=( $hours )
difference=$1
let range=$1-1000
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#array_numbers[@]} ; i++ )) 
do
let num=$(( 10#${array_numbers[$i+1]} - 10#${array_numbers[$i]} ))
   if [ $num -gt $1 ]
     then
       echo ${lines_array[$i+1]} "and" ${lines_array[$i]} "has a difference more than $1"
   elif [ $num -ge 0 ] && [ $num -lt $range ] 
     then
       echo ${lines_array[$i+1]} "and" ${lines_array[$i]} "has a difference more than $1"
   elif [ $num -le $1 ]
     then
       if [${hours_array[$i+1]} != ${hours_array[$i]}]
       then
         echo ${lines_array[$i+1]} "and" ${lines_array[$i]} "has a difference more than one second"
       fi
  fi
done
```

I'm working with the same output2.txt again:

```
12:43:40,317
12:43:40,318
12:43:40,332
12:43:40,333
12:43:40,334
12:43:40,335
12:43:40,336
12:43:40,337
12:43:40,338
12:43:40,339
12:43:40,353
12:43:40,354
12:43:40,356
12:43:40,358
12:43:40,360
12:43:40,361
12:43:40,362
12:43:40,363
12:43:40,364
12:43:40,365
12:43:40,382
12:43:40,384
12:43:40,385
12:43:40,387
12:43:40,388
12:43:40,389
12:43:40,390
12:43:40,391
12:43:40,404
12:43:40,405
12:43:40,406
12:43:40,407
12:43:40,408
12:43:40,409
12:43:40,410
12:43:40,412
12:43:40,413
12:43:40,414
12:43:40,415
12:43:40,428
12:43:40,429
12:43:40,431
12:43:40,432
12:43:40,433
12:43:40,434
12:43:40,435
12:43:40,436
12:43:40,437
12:43:40,438
12:43:40,440
12:43:40,443
12:43:40,458
12:43:40,459
12:43:40,460
12:43:40,461
12:43:40,462
12:43:40,463
12:43:40,464
12:43:40,465
12:43:40,466
12:43:40,479
12:43:40,480
12:43:40,481
12:43:40,482
12:43:40,483
12:43:40,484
12:43:40,485
12:43:40,486
12:43:40,487
12:43:40,501
12:43:40,503
12:43:40,504
12:43:40,505
12:43:40,506
12:43:40,509
12:43:40,510
12:43:40,511
12:43:40,512
12:43:40,513
12:43:40,514
12:43:40,515
12:43:40,517
12:44:40,518
```

What I want to do is take the difference as parameter and if there is a value difference more than 100 miliseconds than I'm wanna print output. The parts

```
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#array_numbers[@]} ; i++ )) 
    do
    let num=$(( 10#${array_numbers[$i+1]} - 10#${array_numbers[$i]} ))
          if [ $num -gt $1 ]
              then
               echo ${lines_array[$i+1]} "and" ${lines_array[$i]} "has a difference more than $1"
          elif [ $num -ge 0 ] && [ $num -lt $range ] 
              then
               echo ${lines_array[$i+1]} "and" ${lines_array[$i]} "has a difference more than $1"
```

are actually working well , but i realized that if input has such a columns in order like the last part

```
12:43:40,517
12:44:40,518
```

it won't print anything so i put the last elif statement to my code but even it prints hours_array good, it doesn't work with while i'm comparing them. The output is always :

> script.sh: line 22: [12:43:00: command not found

Why doesn't it accept this compare or is the problem is about my bash version ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: amusingly, the time taken for reading the code would be less than posting the question here with formatting... (especially since you [already know the syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120920/why-this-command-not-found-when-im-comparing-strings-in-an-array#comment40938266_26121114)...) :D

Comment: yes I already know about this but as I said sometimes being blind is a big problem for us (!!) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space here (the `[` is a command)

```
 if [ ${hours_array[$i+1]} != ${hours_array[$i]} ]
```

Comment: Also quotes to be safe: `if [ "${hours_array[$i+1]}" != "${hours_array[$i]}" ]`; that way, going off the end yields a false comparison rather than letting `test` complain about a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Add space before and after `[`. It is an 'alias' to the `test` buitin command.

You should also add double quote `"` around your variable. Because if they are empty, bash won't recognize them as a empty word.

And I generally use double brackets `[[` for test condition which is more safer and has more features.

Example:

```
if [[ "${hours_array[$i+1]}" != "${hours_array[$i]}" ]]
```

Comment: Great advice, but somewhat redundant -- using `[[ ]]` makes the quotes unnecessary, at least on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Missing space after `[`. `[` is a command, so it needs to be separated from its arguments.

```
if [ ${hours_array[$i+1]} != ${hours_array[$i]} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I find few things that can be changed in this code.

- Add space after `[` and before `]`.
- Add double quotes so that in case if variable is empty, script does not throw error.

  ```
  if [ "${hours_array[$i+1]}" != "${hours_array[$i]}" ]
  ```
- Also when you reach the last line, `$i + 1` will fail. Hence, following would be better.

  ```
  for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#array_numbers[@]} - 1 ; i++ ))
  ```